# Python how to convert String nested list to python list

Tags: python, list

Hi I have this nested list as a string :

```
string = "[['June 15', '21:30', 'Tenerife', 'Malaga', 'Tenerife OR Draw', 1.323, ['Tenerife', 'Draw'], '25961', '397008'], ['June 15', '15:00', 'Surkhon Termez', "Mash'al Mubarek", 'Surkhon Termez OR Draw', 1.287, ['Surkhon Termez', 'Draw'], '231122', '40264'], ['June 15', '19:30', 'Ponferradina', 'Elche', 'Ponferradina OR Draw', 1.334, ['Ponferradina', 'Draw'], '6195', '122164'], ['June 15', '17:00', 'Rigas Futbola Skola', 'FK Ventspils', 'Rigas Futbola Skola OR FK Ventspils', 1.245, ['Rigas Futbola Skola', 'FK Ventspils'], '68718', '5354'], ['June 15', '20:30', 'Arminia Bielefeld', 'Dynamo Dresden', 'Arminia Bielefeld', 1.427, ['Arminia Bielefeld'], '2540', '2595']]"
```

How can I convert this nested list in string form to a python nested list.

Expected format :

```
my_list = []
my_list.append(each list one by one )
```

Comment: The list itself isn't parsed, e.g this entry has a ' sign in it: Mash'al Mubarek

How did you get the list?

Comment: @A.Abramov it's in a txt file , I have use file.readline

Comment: This actually solved my problem : ast.literal_eval(string)

Answer (score -1):

Use the built-in eval() function